# Calling external controllers, Laravel

Tags: php, controller, routes, call, laravel

Having `application/controllers/admin/images/` with `public function get_upload($id=null)` where the controller is set to `restful = true`

How can I call from my News controller, the function above. I try with the following, but I get 404, but the function its self works... calling by a simple `$.post()` works (with the full route obviously)

```
$image = Controller::call('admin.images@upload', array($news_id));
```

Any ideas how should I do it?

### UPDATE

Even with HVMC I still get `404` executing `HMVC::get('admin.images@upload', array('news_id'=>$news_id)`

**applications/controller/admin/images.php**

```
class Admin_Images_Controller extends Admin_Controller
{
     public $restful = true;
     public function get_upload($news_id)
     {
```

P.S. `Admin_Controller` exists and its loaded, it has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [HMVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) which Lavarel doesn't support out-of-the-box. I don't use Lavarel so sorry if I get any information wrong, but a quick search [directs me here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1321), in which they suggest to use [this bundle](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/hmvc).

Upon further inspection, seems like you can use [`Route::forward()`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Routing.Route.html#_forward):

> For most cases you can use Route::forward() to achieve what you're trying to do.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The issue still happens, even with HMVC. I still get `404` executing `HMVC::get('admin.images@upload', array('news_id'=>$news_id));`

Comment: Hmmm give this a try: `$result = \Lavarel\Routing\Route::forward('get', '/admin/images/upload');` (Or whichever route you registered for the method)?

Comment: how would I send the `$news_id` variable?

Comment: From [here](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#controller-routing) it gives you something like this: `http://localhost/controller/method/arguments` (Most frameworks support this type of URI routing) so I assume you could do: `$result = \Lavarel\Routing\Route::forward('get', "/admin/images/upload/{$news_id}");`. Again, never used Lavarel, but give it a try :)

Comment: `\Laravel\Routing\` won't go... removed that and tried with the rest, and still get a 404 :(

Comment: Have you defined your route like so?: `Route::get('admin/images/upload/(:any)', array('uses' => 'admin.images@upload'));`, also try removing the first forward slash from `"/admin/images/upload/{$news_id}"` to `"admin/images/upload/{$news_id}"`, not sure how strict Lavarel is..

Comment: i'll try that later and let you know the result

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same problem. The problem is that if the http type (post, get, put, delete) is different it will return 404.

Eg Say you have 2 controllers, image and media. If you have a function called `POST_UPLOAD` in images controller and another  function called `GET_RESIZE` in media controller, calling `GET_RESIZE` from `POST_UPLOAD` will return a 404 and vice versa

But if `GET_RESIZE` was `POST_RESIZE` the error would not occur ie same http type.

This means that the http type must be the same.

This is bad because you need to maintain 2 function of `RESIZE` ie `GET_RESIZE` & `POST_RESIZE`.

This is something that is not documented in Laravel.

Comment: interesting comment. Anyways I had fixed somehow after all.